# Unresolved class MainActivity Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

I create a new project in Android Studio using Kotlin, after I create it in file AndroidManifes.xml I already have 11 problems:

[It was the first i saw when i opened this file after creating project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tBHg.png)
Also when i open already created project it have the same problems.
[it was already created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl6Si.png)
It doesn't matter what i use Linux or Windows.

MainActivity.java:

```
package ru.myitschool.lab22toast;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import ru.myitschool.lab22toast.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

I tried File->Invalidate Caches->Invalidate and Restart and it didn't help.